# Forward exchange rate historical data?

Tags: finance

I found that the historical data of forward exchange rate is really hard to find, I'm looking for historical data of JPY/USD forward exchange rate, does anyone have experience in this?

Comment: Once you ask for anything over the historical spot, you're adding an extra dimension. For this reason, the quantity of data explodes. For that reason, providing such data becomes more difficult, and so the solutions you'll see for it are all going to be in the non free domain. The data you want definitely exists, and there are a number of providers - which one best fits your needs, and budget, though, I don't. Perhaps someone else will fill that bit in, if you can say what you're looking to pay, and exactly what data you want.